# Did I find the vector projection correctly?

Tags: vectors, convention

I was a bit worried if I followed all the conventions correctly or not.

Let the vector projection of a vector $\vec{a}$ on a non-zero vector $\vec{b}$ is $\vec{a_1}$.

**My attempt:**

$$\vec{a_1}=\frac{(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})\hat{b}}{|\vec{b}|}\tag{1}$$

$$=\frac{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}}{|\vec{b}|}\cdot\frac{\vec{b}}{|\vec{b}|}\tag{2}$$

$$=\frac{(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})\vec{b}}{|\vec{b}|^2}\tag{3}$$

Since $(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b})$ is a scalar, placing $\hat{b}$ next to it to indicate multiplication shouldn't be a problem. Moreover, since $\frac{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}}{|\vec{b}|}$ is a scalar, putting "$\cdot$" between it and $\frac{\vec{b}}{|\vec{b}|}$ in $(2)$ shouldn't be a problem. Finally, as $(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b})$ is a scalar, placing $\vec{b}$ next to it to indicate multiplication in  shouldn't be a problem either. Also, in the wikipedia image below $\mathbf{\left(a\cdot b\right)\hat{b}}$ is written, so we can be certain that writing $(1)$ and $(3)$ is correct.

**Question:**

1. Did I do everything right in $(2)$? I'm worried about the $\cdot$ between $\frac{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}}{|\vec{b}|}$ and $\frac{\vec{b}}{|\vec{b}|}$ in $(2)$.

---

Something similar from Wikipedia:

[image]

Comment: I would not use a $\cdot$ for scalar multiplication in an expression I'm already using it for the dot product. But yes that's correct. And the thing on Wikipedia isn't just "similar," it's literally the same thing. It's not fully clear to me what it is you're "attempting," though. You're just attempting to write down some equivalent formulas for the vector projection?

Comment: "You're just attempting to write down some equivalent formulas for the vector projection?"- yes that's it. I was just a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression $(2)$ is technically correct and ultimately unambiguous, but $$\frac{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}}{|\vec{b}|}\times\frac{\vec{b}}{|\vec{b}|}\tag{2r}$$ is better, and faster to parse, as it doesn't involve any double-checking that the author has indeed used “$\cdot$” to alternately mean dot product and regular multiplication.